# Parameters needed for d3.mouse()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get mouse coordinates relative to a `group` element. Here's the code:

```
var backRect = chart.append("g").attr("class", "rect");
var g = backRect.append('rect')
        .style('stroke', 'none')
        .style('fill', '#FFF')
        .style('fill-opacity', 0)
        .attr({
            width: width,
            height: height,
            'pointer-events': 'none',
            'class': 'backRect'
        });

// the code below is inside another container's event; but I want mouse coordinates relative to the above rect, hence can't use d3.mouse(this)
// get mouse pointer location
        var coordinates = [0, 0];
        coordinates = d3.mouse(backRect); // d3.select(".rect") does not work either
```

but get the following error:

`d3.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: n.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

According to the d3 [mouse](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#mouse) docs `d3.mouse()` takes a container which can be `svg` or `g` element.

What parameter should I pass to `d3.mouse()`? I tried `d3.select(".rect")` which is not working either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `d3.mouse(backRect.node())` did the trick.

Comment: Accept your answer (you can do that in SO)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using d3.mouse() inside an event to get the values relative to the passed container.

Check this block

http://bl.ocks.org/hlucasfranca/f133da4493553963e710

```
svg.on("click", function() {
          var coords = d3.mouse(this);
          ........
          ........
})
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but I am already using `d3.mouse()` in an event(the code above is just a clean version of the original) and needed the mouse coordinates relative to a different container(backRect). Thanks

Comment: You should probably edit your question to make that clear. `d3.mouse(backRect)` doesn't seem to be part of an event function.